How to determine $\Gamma_{15}$?
For context,yesterday I asked How to determine $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\Gamma_3,\Gamma_4,\Gamma_5$?.
Now I learned of new theorem that made me curious:
Theorem:
Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $gcd(m,n)=1$. Then the map $\Omega: \Gamma_n \times \Gamma_m \rightarrow \Gamma_{nm}, (\chi,\chi') \mapsto \chi \chi'$ is a (group)- isomorphism.
In How to determine $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\Gamma_3,\Gamma_4,\Gamma_5$? we determined $\Gamma_3$ and $\Gamma_5$.
Now given $\Gamma_3$ and $\Gamma_5$ the Theorem mentioned should make it possible to calculate $\Gamma_{15}$ in an easy way.
I did calculate $\Gamma_3$ and $\Gamma_5$ explicitly and here are the values:
For $\Gamma_3$ we get the following table:
$\begin{matrix}
\Gamma_3 & k=1 & k=2 \\ 
\chi_0(k) &1  & 1\\ 
\chi_1(k) & 1  & -1 
\end{matrix}$
and for $\Gamma_5$ we get this table ( I denote the elements of $\Gamma_5$ as $\Psi$ for better readability):
$\begin{matrix}
\Gamma_5 & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4\\ 
 \Psi _0(k) &  1& 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 \Psi _1(k)& 1 & -1 &-1  &1 \\ 
 \Psi _2(k)&  1&  i& i &-1 \\ 
 \Psi _3(k)& 1 & -i &i  & -1
\end{matrix}$.
I will denote the elements of $\Gamma_{15}$ as $\Phi$.
$(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^{\times}=\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$.
Now since $gcd(3,5)=1$, the map $\Omega: (\chi,\Psi)  \mapsto \chi \cdot \Psi=\Phi$ is an Isomorphism. And we can calculate the table
$\begin{matrix}
\Gamma_3 \times \Gamma_5 & k=(1,1)  & k=(1,2) &k=(1,3)  &k=(1,4)  &k=(2,1)  & k=(2,2)  & k=(2,3) & k=(2,4)\\ 
 \chi_0 \cdot \Psi_0& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 \chi_0 \cdot \Psi_1& 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 &1 \\ 
 \chi_0 \cdot \Psi_2& 1 & i &i  & -1 & 1 & i & i & -1\\ 
 \chi_0 \cdot \Psi_3& 1 & -i & i & -1 & 1 & -i & i & -1 \\ 
 \chi_1 \cdot \Psi_0& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\ 
 \chi_1 \cdot \Psi_1& 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\ 
\chi_1 \cdot \Psi_2 & 1 & i & i  & -1 & -1 & -i & -i  & 1 \\ 
 \chi_1 \cdot \Psi_3& 1 & -i & i & -1 & -1 & i & -i & 1 
\end{matrix}$
My only problem now is that in this table we have the values for $k=(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)$,.... and so on. Instead I would like to have the proper values for $k$ regarding $\Gamma_{15}$ i.e. $k=1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14$.
The Question now is, how can I assign those tupels $(k_1,k_2)$ to it's corresponding elements (in $(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$)?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

@QiaochuYuan Could you maybe elaborate a little bit?

The Chinese remainder theorem states that the ring homomorphism
$\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ that maps $x + mn\mathbb{Z}$ to $(x + m\mathbb{Z},x + n\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism: Bézout's identity gives us $rm + sn = 1$; then the map taking $(x + m\mathbb{Z},y + n\mathbb{Z})$ to $xsn + yrm + mn\mathbb{Z}$ is a well-defined inverse. (This gives an isomorphism between the groups of units $(\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.) In other words: $xsn + yrm \equiv x \pmod{m}$ and $xsn  + yrm \equiv y \pmod{n}$.
For the case of $(m,n) = (3,5)$, we have for instance that $2 \cdot 3 + (-1) \cdot 5 = 1$, so given $k_1$ and $k_2$ we have $-5k_1 + 6k_2$ (which you may want to reduce mod 15) is congruent to both $k_1$ mod $3$ and $k_2$ mod $5$. For example, the pair $(k_1,k_2)=(2,3)$ (mod 3 and 5) maps to $2 \cdot (-5) + 3 \cdot 6 = 8$.
Now, if you are just trying to build a table, you could take your list of elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^\times$, reduce them mod $3$ and mod $5$, apply the corresponding characters and multiply. (e.g. $(\chi_1 \cdot \Psi_2)(8) = \chi_1(2) \Psi_2(3) = -1 \cdot i$)
